# Emailing Workbook With Macros and All

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that I am trying to email with macros. This way the recipient will also be able to use the macros that are included with the workbook. This will make office life easier for my company. I have tried setting the saved file name to .xlsm, but that causes an error.

This is my code (which is adapted from sources online)

```
Sub MailGo()
 'Variable declaration
Dim oApp As Object, _
oMail As Object, _
WB As Workbook, _
FileName As String, MailSub As String, MailTxt As String

 'Turns off screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 'Makes a copy of the active sheet and save it to
 'a temporary file
ActiveSheet.Copy
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
FileName = "Text.xls"
On Error Resume Next
Kill "C:\" & FileName
On Error GoTo 0
WB.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\Public\Documents" & FileName

 'Creates and shows the outlook mail item
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)
With oMail
    .To = "wesley.x.sherow@us.tel.com"
    .Cc = ""
    .Bcc = ""
    .Subject = "LotInput"
    .Body = "LotInput"
    .Attachments.Add WB.FullName
    .Display
    .send
End With

 'Deletes the temporary file
WB.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
Kill WB.FullName
WB.Close SaveChanges:=False

 'Restores screen updating and release Outlook
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set oMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: There are probably email security settings you can't get around without assistance from your sysAdmin but disabling these safety features is not advisable. Surely, there is a common file share you can save it to then include a link in the email to the file so they can pull the `xlsm` down to their local machine.

Comment: What is the error, and what instruction is causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to also include this argument in your `.SaveAs` line.

```
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful! The only problem that I am encountering with this is that the file format although macro enabled does not preserve the existing macros in the document.